# Display block parent class when element inside has class active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have some problems with this. I have multiple parent divs with the same class and I want when an element inside every parent div has class "selected_tip" to display block the parent of the parent of that element. How to do this. Keep in mind that the id's are dinamic. My code is this:

```html
<div class="tip">
    <div id="tip_1" class="tt tip1">
        <p>Proaspete</p>
        <span class="select_tip select_copt "></span>
    </div>
    <div id="tip_2" class="tt tip2">
        <p>Coapte, tocate</p>
        <span class="select_tip select_copt "></span>
    </div>
    <div id="tip_3" class="tt tip1">
        <p>Călite</p>
        <span class="select_tip select_copt selected_tip"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="tip_4" class="tt tip2">
        <p>Prăjite</p>
        <span class="select_tip select_copt "></span>
    </div>
    <div id="tip_5" class="tt tip1">
        <p>Fierte</p>
        <span class="select_tip select_copt "></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: your question is not so clear ? by my understanding you want to show **class="tip"** div am I right ??

Comment: Parent of the parent is div with class tip, as mentioned, do you want to show all these divs? Please provide more context....

Comment: I made it through. I wanted to show the tip class only when contains a span with selected_tip class. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Is the class allready there when the page loads? Or Is it added later dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$('.selected_tip').closest('div.tip').css('display', 'block')
```

OR, Use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to traverse up to parent.

> Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$('.selected_tip').parent().parent().css('display', 'block')
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't downvoted, someone else did. This is a clear and nice explanation. Thank you again.